# Accessibility: Tabbing on mobile goes behind nav overlay at bottom of viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigation, accessibility

As stated in the title. When you start tabbing it doesn't respect the fact that there is a nav overlay at the bottom of the screen. So certain links and buttons that are hidden behind the overlay will be tabbed to without being in view of the user.

Is there a way for me to override this functionality and force tabbed items into view?

Comment: Can you put your code here? https://codepen.io/stephanmax/pen/daswq or here? https://codepen.io/gsarig/pen/GWgNdx Or, a runnable snippet like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205581/accessible-css-only-tab-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to intercept <kbd>tab</kbd> etc. and adjust the scroll position yourself is one possibility as you have stated but that could potentially lead to unexpected behaviour.

A better way to handle this is to adjust your layout to account for the overlay at the bottom.

In essence all of your main content would sit in a container (this may be the `<main>` element if your overlay at the bottom is an `<aside>` otherwise just use a `<div>`).

Make that container the page height minus the height of the overlay.

That way no content will ever be behind the overlay (which technically is no longer an overlay as nothing goes behind it).

The beauty of this is when you get to the very bottom of the page everything will be visible, with an overlay you may end up with something partially obscured if you don't give it enough margin / padding at the bottom.

Comment: I agree and this is still being worked out so maybe that will be the decision the design team makes

Answer (score 0):

I have found two things:

1. [DocumentOrShadowRoot.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) this would one way we could capture the currently focused button or link.
2. [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) this would be how we force the focused element to the center of the viewport.